# Who is the manufacturer of this window?

Tags: windows

Trying to identify who the manufacturer is of this window.  They have a (W) on the lock lever on the casement window [image]

Comment: How old is it? Is it wood frame or vinyl?  (Good luck, I already have a pretty good idea you won't find an answer)

Comment: Window hardware could be manufactured by a different party than the window itself.

Comment: Might also help to tell us where in the world this window is.  There are many regional vendors and sales popularities.